# Why does one code snippet compile, but the other does not?

Tags: c#, .net

The first compiles and runs . The second one fails because the method call returns an `ICollection`.

The following code works fine

```
foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace)) 
{
    Id = schema.Id;
    Version = schema.Version;             
}
```

Since I am going to to get only one schema, why not go ahead and do this

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace);
Id = schema.Id;
Version = schema.Version;
```

There has to be something which is similar to the second one which will work?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to make the second one work easily:

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace).Cast<XmlSchema>().Single();
Id = schema.Id;
Version = schema.Version;
```

If you're definitely expecting only a single schema, I would definitely opt for using `Single()` instead of `First()` - that way if your expectations are ever mistaken, you'll throw an exception rather than using whichever schema *happened* to come first out of the unexpectedly-large collection.

The `Cast<>()` call is required because `Schemas()` only returns a weakly-typed `ICollection` rather than an implementation of `IEnumerable<XmlSchema>`.

Comment: just curious to know why it returns a weakly typed collection ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina: Presumably because it predates generics.

Comment: most of the guys who answered i think assumed a strongly typed collection ...but the doubt seems to be clear now ... thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Since [`Schemas()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68ax7d.aspx) returns an `ICollection`, you can't convert that to a single `XmlSchema` element. To get the single element from the collection, you need:

```
var schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace).Cast<XmlSchema>().First();
Id = schema.Id;
Version = schema.Version;
```

(This uses LINQ's `IEnumerable.Cast<TResult>` to turn the non-generic collection into a generic one so you obtain a result of the correct type `XmlSchema`, so you may have to add a using directive for `System.Linq`.)

Comment: perfectly explained, but i can only mark one as answer!! Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace).Cast<XmlSchema>().Single();
Id = schema.Id;
Version = schema.Version;
```

The `.Single()` will throw an exception if `.Schemas()` returns 0 items though.

You could also use `.SingleOrDefault()` to ensure that there are no more than 1, but just return null if there are 0:

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace).Cast<XmlSchema>().SingleOrDefault();
if(schema != null)
{
  Id = schema.Id;
  Version = schema.Version;
}
```

Comment: From the original question's code snippet, i wasn't sure what `schemaSet` actually was, so I just assumed it was a generic collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace)` is an IEnumerable you cant assign it to `XmlSchema`.

Try to assign it to `IEnumerable<XmlSchema>`

Afterwards you have to select a defined one. See other answers.

**Please don't ignore XmlSchemas by selecting any.**

Ignoring Information often is the wrong way. There should be a qualified way to find the desired XMLSchema.

In my opinion `First()` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Error is this:

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace);
```

You are trying to return a list of schemas in a single schema object. This will not work.

You can either do:

```
IList<XmlSchema> schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace);
```

and loop.

or this to return a specific schema based upon index.

```
XmlSchema schema = (from s in set.Schemas().Cast<XmlSchema>().ToList()
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: do we have indexes for collections ? XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace)[0]; may not be right ..

Comment: You are right Ashutosh, It never occured to my mind that a collection can't have indexes, so I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent. The first piece of code iterates over the collection and sets the values to the last item in the collection.

To get the same behaviour you need to do a FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() to protect where the .Schemas method returns no elements.

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas(targetNamespace).FirstOrDefault();
if (schema != null)
{
        Id = schema.Id;
        Version = schema.Version;
}
```

EDIT: Noting Jon Skeet's answer add

```
as XmlSchema
```

to the end or do the cast as he mentioned.